# Add variables to an already saved User Defaults variable

Tags: swift, decode, encode, userdefaults

I have downloaded a swift file that should help me with saving and loading custom variables:

```
import Foundation

protocol ObjectSavable {
func setToObject<Object>(_ object: Object, forKey: String) throws where Object: Encodable
func getToObject<Object>(forKey: String, castTo type: Object.Type) throws -> Object where Object: Decodable
}

extension UserDefaults: ObjectSavable {
func setToObject<Object>(_ object: Object, forKey: String) throws where Object: Encodable {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(object)
        set(data, forKey: forKey)
    } catch {
        throw ObjectSavableError.unableToEncode
    }
}

func getToObject<Object>(forKey: String, castTo type: Object.Type) throws -> Object where Object: Decodable {
    guard let data = data(forKey: forKey) else { throw ObjectSavableError.noValue }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let object = try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
        return object
    } catch {
        throw ObjectSavableError.unableToDecode
    }
}
}

enum ObjectSavableError: String, LocalizedError {
case unableToEncode = "Unable to encode object into data"
case noValue = "No data object found for the given key"
case unableToDecode = "Unable to decode object into given type"
}
```

And I have this `Person` struct:

```
struct Person: Encodable, Decodable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var birthday: Date

    init() {
        self.firstName = "Tim"
        self.lastName = "Cook"
        self.birthday = Date()
    }
}
```

And I also have this code for saving/loading a `Person` struct (that is using the code from above)

**Saving:**

```
print("Saving object...")
    let person: Person = Person()
    
    do {
        try UserDefaults.standard.setToObject(person, forKey: "person")
        print("Object saved successfully")
    } catch let err {
        print("Error while saving object:\n\(err.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

**Loading:**

```
print("Loading object...")
    
    do {
        self.person = try UserDefaults.standard.getToObject(forKey: "person", castTo: Person.self)
        print("Successfully load object:\n\(self.person!)")
    } catch let err {
        print("Error while loading object:\n\(err.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Now, all of this **does** work.
But, let's say that I release my app that way, and then I want to add a new variable to `Person`, for example, I'll add a `favorite`:

```
struct Person: Encodable, Decodable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var birthday: Date
    var favorite: Bool = false

    init() {
        self.firstName = "Tim"
        self.lastName = "Cook"
        self.birthday = Date()
    }
}
```

Before the update, the app (without the `favorite` variable in `Person`) would save without the `favorite` variable. And after the update, the app will try to load the previous saved `Person` with the `favorite` variable. And that is where it failes, because the older-version data doesn't have a `favorite` variable in it. So it throws an error.

And my question is, is there a way that when it decoding a `Person` from User Defaults, if it doesn't find any matching variable (for example: `favorite`), instead of throwing an error, it will try to auto-create it? (from `var favorite` **`= false`**)?

My project: https://github.com/orihpt/Encodable

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to add custom decoding code into `Person`:

```
enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
    case firstName
    case lastName
    case birthday
    case favorite
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
    lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
    birthday = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .birthday)
    favorite = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .favorite) ?? false
}
```

Note that for `favorite`, I used `decodeIfPresent` and defaults to `false`.

---

Another way is to declare `favorite` as optional:

```
var favorite: Bool?
```

This will cause `favorite` to be set to `nil` if it doesn't exist in the data, not the `false` that you want. If you really want `false`, you can use an implicitly unwrapped optional `Bool?`, and you'd need to change the `nil` to `false` every time you decode:

```
self.person = try UserDefaults.standard.getToObject(forKey: "person", castTo: Person.self)
if self.person.favorite == nil {
    self.person.favorite = false
}
```

If you are afraid that you might forget to do this, you can make `getToObject` only accept objects that conform to this protocol:

```
protocol HasDefaults {
    func changeNilsToDefaults()
}


extension UserDefaults {
    func getToObject<Object: HasDefaults>(forKey: String, castTo type: Object.Type) throws -> Object where Object: Decodable {
        guard let data = data(forKey: forKey) else { throw ObjectSavableError.noValue }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let object = try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
            object.changeNilsToDefaults() // notice this line!
            return object
        } catch {
            throw ObjectSavableError.unableToDecode
        }
    }
}
```

And you won't be able to do `getToObject(forKey: "person", castTo: Person.self)` unless you conform `Person` to `HasDefaults`:

```
extension Person : HasDefaults {
    func changeNilsToDefaults() {
        if self.person.favorite == nil {
            self.person.favorite = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sweeper's suggestions are working solutions. You can also merge his "Optional" approach with DTO solution.

> [DTO: Data transfer object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

Save your objects as DTO objects and add new properties as Optional after first release:

```
struct PersonDTO: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let birthday: Date
    let favorite: Bool?
}
```

After getting the DTO object from UserDefaults, initialize your Person object with it.

```
struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var birthday: Date
    var favorite: Bool

    init(_ dto: PersonDTO) {
        self.firstName = dto.firstName
        self.lastName = dto.lastName
        self.birthday = dto.birthday
        self.favorite = dto.favorite ?? false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Create a `protected` variable:

```
struct Person: Encodable, Decodable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var birthday: Date
    var favorite: Bool {
        get {
            return favoriteProtected ?? false
        }
        set {
            favoriteProtected = newValue
        }
    }

    private var favoriteProtected: Bool? = nil

    init() {
        self.firstName = "Tim"
        self.lastName = "Cook"
        self.birthday = Date()
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)`, which can take a long time if your `struct` is big.